# How to add border to circular image on hover? css or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to web designing and I am trying to figure out how I can add a circular border to circular image on hover. I am using the image below. I want to add a border of red color to it on hover. It already has a gray border. I want the border to overlap with the the built in border. Can anyone please help me in figuring out the best way of doing it? I dont know much jquery. It will be great if the solution is in css.

[image: Circular Image]

Comment: If you show us what you have tried or set up a jsfiddle it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I am using framework to built a page. I have simply used fuild grids to built it. one half of page is having a text block and other side is having a circle image. I want to change the border color of text div and want to add circular border to circular image. That's it

Comment: Here is a great tutorial that should help you out - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/

Comment: this tutorial is awesome thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `:hover` pseudo selector.

```
.circ:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #f0b;
}
```

Example:

```css
.circ {
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #ddd;
}

.circ:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #f0b;
}
```

```html
<img class="circ" src="//placehold.it/150x150/0bf">
```

Comment: This works, thanks. And one more question Can I also change the border of a rectangular div on the same time. If some one hovers on circle or either the rectangular div, borders of both should change change.

Comment: @user3311189 if they share the same parent yes, you just set the hover on the parent element, otherwise you can do it with JavaScript or a bit of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the css code to add a circle border to an object then change that border to red on hover.

```
#circle{
    height:400PX;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#circle:hover{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

You don't need to set the border the first time but I added this to showcase the effect. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to create the circle with CSS because the image really isn't circular.

Comment: Agreed with Jay. Roko's answer looks best fitting.